# UIImage color changing?

Tags: ios, uiimage

How can I change the UIImage's color through programming, any help please? If I send a UIImage, its color needs to change any help please? If I change the RGB color through bitmaphandling, it does not work.

Comment: Isn't the class just an image and not a color? What exactly are you asking?

Comment: U can check this link. It works well. http://coffeeshopped.com/2010/09/iphone-how-to-dynamically-color-a-uiimage

Answer (score 36):

If you only need it to *look* different, just use `imageView.tintColor` (iOS 7+).  Catch is, setting `tintColor` doesn't do anything by default:

[image: Why isn't my image blue? I'm setting tintColor...]

To make it work, use `imageWithRenderingMode:`

```
var image = UIImage(named: "stackoverflow")!
image = image.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysTemplate)

let imageView = ...
imageView.tintColor = UIColor(red: 0.35, green: 0.85, blue: 0.91, alpha: 1)
imageView.image = image
```

And now it will work:

[image: Now the image is orange!]

[Link to documentation.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857-UIView-SW7)

---

**Performance**

Setting the image after configuring the `UIImageView` avoids repeating expensive operations:

```
// Good usage
let imageView = ...
imageView.tintColor = yourTintColor
var image = UIImage(named: "stackoverflow")!
image = image.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysTemplate)
imageView.image = image        // Expensive

// Bad usage
var image = UIImage(named: "stackoverflow")!
image = image.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysTemplate)
let imageView = ...
imageView.image = image        // Expensive
imageView.frame = ...          // Expensive
imageView.tintColor = yourTint // Expensive
```

Getting & setting the image asynchronously reduces scrolling and animation lag (especially when tinting an image inside of a `UICollectionViewCell` or `UITableViewCell`):

```
let imageView = cell.yourImageView
imageView.image = nil // Clear out old image
imageView.tintColor = UIColor(red: 0.35, green: 0.85, blue: 0.91, alpha: 1)

// Setting the image asynchronously reduces stuttering 
// while scrolling.  Remember, the image should be set as
// late as possible to avoid repeating expensive operations
// unnecessarily.
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
    var image = UIImage(named: "stackoverflow")!
    image = image.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysTemplate)
    imageView.image = image
})
```

Comment: Actually the attached image is incorrect. It is with white background but it should be with transparent background.

Comment: @Voloda2 You are right, you'll need an image with transparency.

Comment: how does it go in objective-c

Comment: I am having this problem with a `UIButton` that I use within a `UIBarButtonItem`. Which image should be set? I configured the image I set in the button with `setImage(for: .normal)`, but it makes no difference.

Answer (score 7):

One way to accomplish this is to desaturate your image, and add a tint on top of that image with the color you desire.

**Desaturate**

```
-(UIImage *) getImageWithUnsaturatedPixelsOfImage:(UIImage *)image {
    const int RED = 1, GREEN = 2, BLUE = 3;

    CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width*2, image.size.height*2);

    int width = imageRect.size.width, height = imageRect.size.height;

    uint32_t * pixels = (uint32_t *) malloc(width*height*sizeof(uint32_t));
    memset(pixels, 0, width * height * sizeof(uint32_t));

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pixels, width, height, 8, width * sizeof(uint32_t), colorSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);

    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height), [image CGImage]);

    for(int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        for(int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            uint8_t * rgbaPixel = (uint8_t *) &pixels[y*width+x];
            uint32_t gray = (0.3*rgbaPixel[RED]+0.59*rgbaPixel[GREEN]+0.11*rgbaPixel[BLUE]);

            rgbaPixel[RED] = gray;
            rgbaPixel[GREEN] = gray;
            rgbaPixel[BLUE] = gray;
        }
    }

    CGImageRef newImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);

    CGContextRelease(context);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    free(pixels);

    UIImage * resultUIImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:newImage scale:2 orientation:0];
    CGImageRelease(newImage);

    return resultUIImage;
}
```

**Overlay With Color**

```
-(UIImage *) getImageWithTintedColor:(UIImage *)image withTint:(UIColor *)color withIntensity:(float)alpha {
    CGSize size = image.size;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, FALSE, 2);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    [image drawAtPoint:CGPointZero blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor);
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeOverlay);
    CGContextSetAlpha(context, alpha);

    CGContextFillRect(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGRectMake(CGPointZero.x, CGPointZero.y, image.size.width, image.size.height));

    UIImage * tintedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return tintedImage;
}
```

**How-To**

```
//For a UIImageView
yourImageView.image = [self getImageWithUnsaturatedPixelsOfImage:yourImageView.image];
yourImageView.image = [atom getImageWithTintedColor:yourImageView.image withTint:[UIColor redColor] withIntensity:0.7];

//For a UIImage
yourImage = [self getImageWithUnsaturatedPixelsOfImage:yourImage];
yourImage = [atom getImageWithTintedColor:yourImageView.image withTint:[UIColor redColor] withIntensity:0.7];
```

*You can change the color of the tint to whatever you desire.*

Comment: Hey this works great, but I noticed that when using both of these methods on a PNG file with transparency - even the transparent pixels are tinted. Any solutions?

Comment: To override source color to your color using source alpha use this blend mode(R = S*Da):    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeSourceIn); in method getImageWithTintedColor

Answer (score 2):

Check out my [post (mostly just remixing code)](http://compileyouidontevenknowyou.blogspot.com/2010/12/change-colors-of-uiimage-using-uicolor.html).

**Edit**: This code basically creates a new `CGContext`, draws a layer on it with the new color, and returns a new `UIImage` from that. I haven't gone in depth on this code in a while, but it seems to just draw a `UIImage` with the same shape as the original, so that's a limit (loses any detail in the image).

Comment: that original code does not work for gray colors, but the comment one is correct.

Answer (score 2):

There's a great post about this here:
http://coffeeshopped.com/2010/09/iphone-how-to-dynamically-color-a-uiimage

The one caveat that I have with the current code is that using it on retina images will result in a loss of the higher 'resolution' for these images.  I am currently looking for a solution for this...

Comment: I found this link to work best for me. The only change I made was the one recommended in the comments of that post: using kCGBlendModeColor instead of kCGBlendModeColorBurn made the blend mode work better. I also rewrote it in swift - see my other answer for this thread.

Answer (score 2):

If you need high performance, I strongly recommend you to use `GPUImage`.
You may download it at https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage

Answer (score 1):

The RGB data you are operating on is just a copy.  After you finish making changes, you need to turn that data back into an image.

I first make a new bitmap:

```
CGColorSpaceRef space = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate( malloc(dataSize), width, height,
                                8, //   CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(cgImage),
                                bytesPerRow, //CGImageGetBytesPerRow(cgImage),
                                space,
                                //kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Big );
                                kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little);
                                //kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst  | kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little);

    CGColorSpaceRelease( space );

// now draw the image into the context
CGRect rect = CGRectMake( 0, 0, CGImageGetWidth(cgImage), CGImageGetHeight(cgImage) );
CGContextDrawImage( ctx, rect, cgImage );
```

And get the pixels:

```
pixels = CGBitmapContextGetData( ctx );
```

Assuming that your pixel data came from `pixels = CGBitmapContextGetData( ctx );` then take that context and build a new image from it:

```
CGImageRef newImg = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctx);
[[UIImage imageWithCGImage:newImg] drawInRect:rect];
CGImageRelease(newImg);
```

Comment: did it work for you? i tried , it did not give result please?

Comment: You're doing something wrong, and I can't tell you what it is without knowing what you do after you change the bitmap.  How do you turn that back into an image?

Search for "[iphone] bitmap image" here on StackOverflow.  There are tons of questions and answers.

Comment: To make sure you are getting the pixel data correctly, read this http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/qa/qa2007/qa1509.html.

Comment: i did exactly what apple has told, see my question again please.....?
returned image is not in black....bcos i have used r-0,g-0,b-0
please

Comment: you need to ignore the transparent part.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create another context with setting there context color to RGB you want to color your picture. Then draw your UIImage into that context and use that context instead of using directly your picture. This is a concept. This way you're creating offscreen buffer with a colored image. I didn't try this in cocoa, only in carbon, but i suppose it will work in the same way.

Comment: i get the context from that image using UIGraphicsBeginImageContext.
but it did not work?

Comment: Please see this thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112947/how-to-create-a-uiimage-from-the-current-graphics-context
So first set the current color in that context to the RGB you want to color your picture and then draw the picture. After you did it, use the context you've created, not the original picture

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm -- isn't the order of the bytes supposed to be RGBA?  You are setting them as ARGB...

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
- (UIImage *)imageWithOverlayColor:(UIColor *)color
{
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, self.size.width, self.size.height);

    if (UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions) {
        CGFloat imageScale = 1.0f;
        if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)])  // The scale property is new with iOS4.
            imageScale = self.scale;
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.size, NO, imageScale);
    }
    else {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.size);
    }

    [self drawInRect:rect];

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeSourceIn);

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor);
    CGContextFillRect(context, rect);

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The great post mentioned by user576924 worked great for me: 
[iPhone: How to Dynamically Color a UIImage](http://coffeeshopped.com/2010/09/iphone-how-to-dynamically-color-a-uiimage)

and in swift:

```
extension UIImage {

    func imageWithColor( color : UIColor ) -> UIImage {

       // begin a new image context, to draw our colored image onto
       UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.size)

       // get a reference to that context we created
       let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

       // set the fill color
       color.setFill()

       // translate/flip the graphics context (for transforming from CG* coords to UI* coords
       CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, self.size.height)
       CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0)

       // set the blend mode to color burn, and the original image
       CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeColor)
       let rect = CGRect(origin: CGPointZero, size: self.size)
       CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, self.CGImage)

       // set a mask that matches the shape of the image, then draw (color burn) a colored rectangle
       CGContextClipToMask(context, rect, self.CGImage)
       CGContextAddRect(context, rect)
       CGContextDrawPath(context,kCGPathFill)

       // generate a new UIImage from the graphics context we drew onto
       let coloredImg = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
       UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

       //return the color-burned image
       return coloredImg
   }
```

}

Note that I also changed "kCGBlendModeColorBurn" to "kCGBlendModeColor" as mentioned in the post's comments section.

Comment: I get an error that 'kCGPathFill' is an unresolved identifier. What do I need to import? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For me this worked:

```
extension UIImage {
    class func image(image: UIImage, withColor color: UIColor) -> UIImage {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(image.size.width, image.size.height), false, image.scale)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        color.set()
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, image.size.height)
        CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1, -1)
        let rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height)
        CGContextClipToMask(context, rect, image.CGImage)
        CGContextFillRect(context, rect)
        let coloredImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return coloredImage
    }
}
```