# Change UIImage base color, keep white

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uibutton, uiimage

I was trying to use the method outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1698971/uiimage-color-changing) for changing the color of a UIImage used for a UIView. I was hoping this method would ignore whitespace but it does not.

Here is the original image in which I'd like to replace the red with blue.

[image]

Here is the code

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"star-badge"];
image = [image imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysTemplate];

UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:...];
imageView.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];
imageView.image = image;
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
```

but this is the result

[image]

is there a way to ignore the white space or only change the red color?

Comment: Change the original image so that the middle is transparent instead of white, then the method you're using should work.  If need be, display it on a white background.

Answer (score 3):

Change the original image so that the middle is transparent instead of white, then the method you're using should work. If need be, display it on a white background.

Comment: Thanks, will try. Out of curiosity, what if the star had to be black or some color other than white? You'd have to add a background in that case?

Comment: Yeah, the easiest way to handle it would be with a smaller background (so it doesn't show behind the rounded colors) in whatever color you want the star to be.

Comment: Alternatively, there's some ideas [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1698971/uiimage-color-changing) for changing specific colors in an image.  You could also probably do something with the newer `CoreImage`

Comment: [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_filer_recipes/ci_filter_recipes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001185-CH4-SW1) in the `CoreImage` documentation it talks about color keying, which is basically what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

As David says, you need a transparent star, attached the image how should be just in case you cant handle it on photoshop

[image: Modified Image]