# How draw line/arcs on CIImage?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-image

I have a CIImage and I am trying to draw lines on mouse drag along the path. Can I do that ?

I am building an app for mac, and I am new to Core Image.

Answer (score -1):

You need create a graphics context first and then retrieve your image from that. Here's a link that will answer your question. It's for the iPhone but Mac and iPhone are very similar.

[How to create a UIImage from the current graphics context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112947/how-to-create-a-uiimage-from-the-current-graphics-context)