# the paper folding/unfolding effect in twitter for iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, core-animation

Twitter for iPad implements a fancy "pinch to expand paper fold" effect.  A short video clip here.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B0TuPsNJ-XY

Can this be done with `CATransform3D` without OpenGL? A working example would be thankful.

**Update:** I was interested in the approach or implementation to this animation effect. That's why I offered bounty on this question - srikar

Comment: Thanks for posting the video of that awesome effect. Had no idea Twitter did that. :)

Comment: Wow, bounty works! Thank you for offering the bounty,  @Srikar.

Comment: yupp bounty works :) thanks to the wonderful community...

Comment: Hi Guillaume
I am trying to find the code of the above paper fold animation that is developed by twitter. can you please help me out.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Here's a really simple example using a gesture recognizer and `CATransform3D` to get you started.  Simply pinch to rotate the gray view.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // ...

    CGRect rect = self.window.bounds;
    view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(rect.size.width/4, rect.size.height/4,
                                                         rect.size.width/2, rect.size.height/2)];
    view.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    [self.window addSubview:view];

    CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
    transform.m34 = -1/500.0; // this allows perspective
    self.window.layer.sublayerTransform = transform;

    UIPinchGestureRecognizer *rec = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                              action:@selector(pinch:)];
    [self.window addGestureRecognizer:rec];
    [rec release];

    return YES;
}

- (void)pinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)rec
{
    CATransform3D t = CATransform3DIdentity;
    t = CATransform3DTranslate(t, 0, -self.view.bounds.size.height/2, 0);
    t = CATransform3DRotate(t, rec.scale * M_PI, 1, 0, 0);
    t = CATransform3DTranslate(t, 0, -self.view.bounds.size.height/2, 0);
    self.view.layer.transform = t;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of the two CATransform3DTranslate method calls.

Comment: @haroldcampbell The goal of those is to rotate around the edge of the layer, rather than the center.

Comment: That should be done by setting the anchorPoint property of the layer though.

Comment: Don't forget to #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h> 

Great example :)

Answer (score 4):

Essentially, this effect is comprised of several different steps:

1. Gesture recognizer to detect when a pinch-out is occurring.
2. When the gesture starts, Twitter is likely creating a [graphics context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112947/how-to-create-a-uiimage-from-the-current-graphics-context) for the top and bottom portion, essentially creating images from their layers.*
3. Attach the images as subviews on the top and bottom.
4. As the fingers flex in and out, use a `CATransform3D` to [add perspective](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/347721/uiview-perspective-transform) to the images.
5. Once the view has 'fully stretched out', make the real subviews visible and remove the graphics context-created images.

To collapse the views, do the inverse of the above.

*Because these views are relatively simple, they may not need to be rendered to a graphics context.

Answer (score 1):

The effect is basically just a view rotating about the X axis: when you drag a tweet out of the list, there's a view that starts out parallel to the X-Z plane. As the user un-pinches, the view rotates around the X axis until it comes fully into the X-Y plane. The [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Articles/Layers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006082-SW10) says:

> The CATransform3D data structure
>   defines a homogenous three-dimensional
>   transform (a 4 by 4 matrix of CGFloat
>   values) that is used to rotate, scale,
>   offset, skew, and apply perspective
>   transformations to a layer.

Furthermore, we know that CALayer's `transform` property is a CATransform3D structure, and that it's also animatable. Ergo, I think it's safe to say that the folding effect in question is do-able with Core Animation.