# OS X Lion's mail expanding animation on iPhone's UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, animation, osx-lion

Is possible to implement this kind of animation (Screenshot below) on UITableView when expanding a hidden group of cells/rows?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps, but it would be quite difficult. Mail actually uses a Quartz Composer composition to implement this:

[image]

You can't use Quartz Composer on the iPhone, so you would have to do it using CALayers. See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385898/the-paper-folding-unfolding-effect-in-twitter-for-ipad/6502349#6502349) as a potential starting point, but I'm afraid it will be more trouble than it's worth.