# Rotate part of a single UIView on y axis at a given angle

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, rotation, calayer

Guys how can we rotate only a part of UIView at a given angle, my specific requirement is to rotate 25% of left portion of a view at 45 degree or any given angle .. please refer diagram

[image]

I read some article on 3D transform but it involves the entire view rather than a part, I know it is possible as flip animation definitely uses this under the hood any article or any code will be a real help .

Comment: Can you not have a subView for the part which you want to animate? Then you can use the existing 3d animation API's.

Comment: Well yaa thats one of the way to do it, I tried that but I need a way to fold a single UIView at particular angle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look at this ones:

[iOS Paper fold (origami / accordion) effect animation, with manual control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11157888/ios-paper-fold-origami-accordion-effect-animation-with-manual-control)
and
https://github.com/geraldhuard/YFoldView
https://github.com/honcheng/PaperFold-for-iOS