# How do I make a UIImage (screenshot) from the contents of a popover?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uipopover

I'm presenting a popover from a button, in the popover users can make a drawing. I'd like to capture this drawing as a UIImage.

At the moment the drawing is a simple line drawing using UIBezierPath, similar to this tutorial: http://soulwithmobiletechnology.blogspot.com/2011/05/uibezierpath-tutorial-for-iphone-sdk-40.html

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1112947/how-to-create-a-uiimage-from-the-current-graphics-context

Comment: Thanks! I got it working. I couldn't find renderInContext, needed to add the import #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>. The post steered me in the right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone else comes across this. If you can't find renderInContext just 
`#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`

Answer (score 0):

for an actual copy paste solution:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

- (UIImage*) screenShot {

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(_view.bounds.size);
[_view.layer renderInContext: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(); //renders view to an image
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return viewImage;

}
```